# Closure Variable is not assigned

Tags: javascript, closures

Simply i have the following:

```
jQuery.fn.X = function(){
    var elements = jQuery(this);
    elements.click(function(){
        var self = jQuery(this);
        //elements here is not defined why?
    });
```

why `elements` is not defined at the on click function while it should take it as a closure variable ?

Comment: Unless `elements` was re-assigned before the click handler occurs it will not be "not defined" (`undefined`?) there - and yes, the *variable* is bound in a closure. The code is either incomplete context or the observed symptoms are incorrect.

Comment: @Hogan: He may don't want to use `this`. Because, it will point to one `element` in `elements`.

Comment: Did anyone explain that he is changing the prototype, not creating a closure?

Comment: What do you mean @Hogan

Comment: @Hilmi - elements of a prototype are copied into a new object so they don't have the closure -- they have an empty closure -- that is why elements was not defined on your function's call -- it was called from "somewhere else" that did not have the same closure.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct approach to creating a jQuery plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.X = function () {
    // here, "this" will be a jQuery object containing all elements you matched
    // with X(). You must return that object.
    return this.click(function () {
        // here, "this" will be a DOM element. You don't have to return it.
        var self = jQuery(this);
        // ...
    });
});
```

You must return jQuery in order to keep the method chaining working.

Comment: you forgot each. jquery chainable should treat all mathing elements

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, I didn't. You don't have to use `each()`. `click()` will also treat all matching elements, just like almost every other jQuery API function.

Comment: Well. I'd do `$.fn.plugin_name = function ()
   {
 return this.each(function() {
   
 });
};
`

Comment: @RoyiNamir That's unnecessary. And slower, more wasteful than the approach above, too.

Comment: @RoyiNamir That's only if you need to individually process/manipulate each element in the possible collection. Since `.click()` can be applied to all elements, and it's the **only** thing done, it's not necessary to use `each`. In most other cases, it **is** "necessary" to use `each`

Comment: @Ian but what if i want that each click will return the specific ID ? i'd have to use each...

Comment: @Ian In "most" other cases?! In *every* other case that uses a jQuery API function that returns jQuery it's not necessary to use `each()`. In all other cases you can `return this`, unless you do not want method chaining to continue.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Click handlers can't return anything. And when you call `.click()` on a collection, the callback refers to the specific element being clicked. Just like if you did `$(".class").click(function () { /* CODE */ });` - the value of `this` **inside** the callback will refer to whatever element was actually clicked

Comment: @Tomalak True, but I don't see many cases where a plugin simply calls a jQuery method and that's it...

Comment: @Tomalak so `return each` is only when  i want continue chaining  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, you can return *any* jQuery object in order to continue the chain. Think `.parent()`, which returns a different jQuery object (namely all the parents of what was passed in). If you want to keep the chain on the current list of objects, you must `return this` - or, because `this.each()` returns `this` *itself*, you can also simply `return this.each()`.

Comment: _this.each() returns this itself_ ??

Comment: @Ian I see. I took your statement (*"it's necessary to use `each`"*) at face value, so I objected. My core point is in my longer comment above. :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir `each()` returns the exact same jQuery object it operated on, so yes, it "returns itself". (`($x = $("a"); $y = $x.each(function () { /* ... */ }); alert($x === $y);` will alert `true`)

Comment: @Tomalak Thank's I didnt know that. So only if i need to return a `different` element for each item  in the jq array -- Then -- I should use `each` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamirYou should return whatever list of elements you want to continue the chain with. `each` (and `click`, etc) return the list of elements you began with. If that's what you need semantically, use them. The point is that almost every jQuery operation is a "set operation" that uses `each` internally. Breaking the set into single bits by using `each` yourself might just be unnecessary - like in the case above.